# Log4j2 AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher: frozen thread, potential deadlock?

Tags: java, asynchronous, log4j2, deadlock

YourKit warns about a potential deadlock in Log4j2's `AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher`:

```
Potential deadlock: frozen threads found

It seems that the following threads have not changed their stack for more than 10 seconds.
These threads are possibly (but not necessarily!) in a deadlock or hung.

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                              Name                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  +---Log4j2-AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher-2-Async Frozen for at least 9m 2s <Ignore a false positive>                           |
|    |                                                                                                                           |
|    +---jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) Unsafe.java (native)                                                       |
|    |                                                                                                                           |
|    +---java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Object) LockSupport.java:194                                                |
|    |                                                                                                                           |
|    +---java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081      |
|    |                                                                                                                           |
|    +---java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take() ArrayBlockingQueue.java:417                                              |
|    |                                                                                                                           |
|    +---org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.dispatchAll() AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.java:71  |
|    |                                                                                                                           |
|    +---org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.run() AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.java:63          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Log4j2's config (simplified):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" packages="com.mycompany.logging">

    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="RollingJson"
                     fileName="logs/application.log.json" filePattern="logs/application.log.json.%i"
                     bufferedIO="true" bufferSize="1024">
            <MyCompanyJsonLayout/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingJson"/>
        </Async>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${env:LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Not sure how to investigate further, is this warning a false positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a false positive. Since you are using the `Async` appender, you have an instance of the [`AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.java) thread that is waiting for other threads to fill the log message queue.

That is perfectly normal if there are no messages to be logged.

Answer (score 1):

I want to confirm that this is a false positive. And this issue was addressed in the upcoming version 2022.9 of YourKit Java Profiler https://www.yourkit.com/eap/